# Let us now tum to the

Tags: meaning

I found this phrase in a book and intuitively I understand what does it mean, but I want some explanations on how to use, what does it mean exactly and is it deprecated; most of dictionaries translate me 'tum' as a stomach

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Thank you for your question. Can you provide more context? Where did you find this particular expression? Can you give an example? It is always a good idea to visit the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find ideas on how to make a great question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly based on a misreading and is thus of no conceivable interest to English language and usage.

Comment: t u r n mashes up into tum.  See? It's a clergyman asking you to turn the page, or turn you attention to something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not "TUM" it's "TURN". Either you're misreading it, or it's already been misread, perhaps by an OCR system.

Comment: It'd only note that a lower-case 'r' and 'n', as in *'rn'*, will tend to bleed together if there is even the slightest issue with kerning of the letters. So it's extremely easy for 'turn' to turn into 'tum'.

Comment: ... and *burn* into *bum*. Caveat lector.

Comment: of course :) so easy. thanks. I'll accept it in few minutes